# using IN clause in spring-data-cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I'm using spring-data-cassandra 1.4.2.RELEASE.

i want to use IN clause in my query, but i got a error message like below,

> encountered unsupported query parameter type [class [Ljava.lang.String;] 
>   in method public abstract java.util.List a.b.c.SampleRepository.testInCondition(int,java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception

this is how i make a repository code.

```
public interface SampleRepository extends CassandraRepository<SampleObject>{
        @Query("select a, b, v from table_name where a = ?0 and b in (?1);")
        List<SampleObject> testInCondition(int num1, String[] values) throws Exception;
}
```

When i using array(String[]) as a parameter, i got error message.

And i figure out allowed parameter is only like this.

> public static final List> ALLOWED_PARAMETER_TYPES = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays
>               .asList(new Class[] { String.class, CharSequence.class, char.class, Character.class, char[].class, long.class,
>                       Long.class, boolean.class, Boolean.class, BigDecimal.class, BigInteger.class, double.class, Double.class,
>                       float.class, Float.class, InetAddress.class, Date.class, UUID.class, int.class, Integer.class }));

there's no array types.

How can i use IN Clause with spring cassandra.

There's no one knows which spring-data-cassandra version support array type.
Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try tu use list instead of Array? You can easily convert an array to a list with `java.lang.Arrays.asList(...)`

Comment: Spring Data Cassandra 1.4.x and earlier suffer from an incomplete implementation of collection value handling with string-based queries. That's fixed with Spring Data Cassandra 1.5, currently available as RC1 (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-122).